# Python - Calendar Experts - Whether My Algorithm And Logics Correct Or Not?

Tags: python, calendar, jodatime

I did some research and wrote a program in Python to show Hijri(Islamic calendar) Date in this format...

> weekday_name, date, month, year

I want to use this within one of my Apps. Just wanted to know whether my codes are correct or not. I am no way near of a Calendar expert. I am confused whether my code is missing anything and in the end the date mislead people! Can anyone check the code and let me know if I am doing anything wrong?

```
#Get current date.
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
year = now.year
month = now.month
day = now.day
weekday_number = now.weekday()

#Convert current date to Julian date.
from calverter import Calverter
cal = Calverter()
julian = cal.gregorian_to_jd(year,month,day)


#Convert Julian date to Islamic date.
hijri = cal.jd_to_islamic(julian)


#Convert Islamic date to weekday_name, day_number, month_name, year format.
hijri_year = hijri[0]
hijri_month = hijri[1]
hijri_day_number = hijri[2]
hijri_date = [weekday_number, hijri_day_number, hijri_month, hijri_year]


#Convert hijri_month (which are in number forms) into month names.
if hijri_month == 1:
    hijri_date[2] = "Muharram"
elif hijri_month == 2:
    hijri_date[2] = "Safar"
elif hijri_month == 3:
    hijri_date[2] = "Rabi al Awwal"
elif hijri_month == 4:
    hijri_date[2] = "Rabi ath Thani"
elif hijri_month == 5:
    hijri_date[2] = "Jamada al Ula"
elif hijri_month == 6:
    hijri_date[2] = "Jumada ath Thaniyah"
elif hijri_month == 7:
    hijri_date[2] = "Rajab"
elif hijri_month == 8:
    hijri_date[2] = "Shaban"
elif hijri_month == 9:
    hijri_date[2] = "Ramadan"
elif hijri_month == 10:
    hijri_date[2] = "Shawal"
elif hijri_month == 11:
    hijri_date[2] = "Dhu al Qa'dah"
elif hijri_month == 12:
    hijri_date[2] = "Dhu al Hijah"


#Convert weekday_numbers into weekday names.
if weekday_number == 0:
    hijri_date[0] = "Al Ithnayn"
elif weekday_number == 1:
    hijri_date[0] = "Ath Thulatha"
elif weekday_number == 2:
    hijri_date[0] = "Al Arbia"
elif weekday_number == 3:
    hijri_date[0] = "Al khamis"
elif weekday_number == 4:
    hijri_date[0] = "Al Jumuah"
elif weekday_number == 5:
    hijri_date[0] = "As Sabt"
elif weekday_number == 6:
    hijri_date[0] = "Al Ahad"

print hijri_date
```

I used pycalverter library to do some stuffs. If anyone wants I can post the code of open source pycalverter in a pastebin.

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Give us an example of expected output and actual output

Comment: @Vaibhav Mule I myself want to know if there is any logical mistake before deploying my App with this module. :)

Comment: If there is not identifiable problem, then this is off topic for StackOverflow. Consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but you should *test* your code before posting there.

Comment: @jpmc26 Please note that [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) is not for "tell me whether my code is correct or not", but rather is for "My code is correct--how do I make it better?"

Comment: @jpmc26 checking code for correctness is not in scope for codereview.se... Code submitted there is required to be "working to the best of your knowledge" which is clearly not the case here. For more information, please refer to the [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Apologies. That's what I was trying to address by instructing the user to test their code first, but your statements are a lot more clear on the matter.

Comment: @jpmc26 did you see discussion between me and sobolevn? Here was an issue. He helps me to reduce remarkable number of statements and CPU works by giving his valuable reply.

Comment: @LeoDevlar It doesn't matter what response is given. Unless you have a *specific, narrowly defined problem*, it's off topic for StackOverflow. If you had asked a question specifically about improving performance (**which would have to include an explanation of why it's too slow**), that would be on topic. "Check my code" is *never* on topic.

Comment: @jpmc26 this is my first day in SOF. So probably I don't know all rules and regulations of SOF till now. However why downvoting a newbie? When I am completely new?

Comment: @LeoDevlar We downvote questions, not users. See the first half of [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9961), especially this: "The up/down vote system is not just about rep, it is the quality control mechanism for Stack Exchange."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things I would suggest.

Firstly, if you are not sure, if your code is correct or not (and even if you are sure) - write and run tests. You can use a testing library (such as [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) and etc.) or just implement some simple tests to make sure everything is working as you expect. If you are new to testing, you can find [a lot](http://pythontesting.net/) of [articles](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/tests/) about it in the web.

Secondly, all your `if`s could be replaced with two lists (one for months and one for days):

```
# Just define 12 months names:
islamic_months = ["Muharram", "Safar", "Rabi al Awwal", 
                  "Rabi ath Thani", "Jamada al Ula", 
                  "Jumada ath Thaniyah", "Rajab", "Shaban", 
                  "Ramadan", "Shawal", "Dhu al Qa'dah", "Dhu al Hijah"]
# On the next step get the right name: 
hijri_date[2] = islamic_months[hijri_month - 1] # 1 <= hijri_month <= 12
```

And the same with days:

```
islamic_day_names = ["Al Ithnayn", "Ath Thulatha", "Al Arbia",
                     "Al khamis", "Al Jumuah", "As Sabt", "Al Ahad"]
hijri_date[0] = islamic_day_names[weekday_number] # 0 <= weekday_number <= 6
```

The main idea is that you don't have to check which day or month it is. Just use its index to get the proper name from the list.

Comment: @sovolevn I tried to upvote you but it says I need 15 reputations to upvote you. Otherwise I could upvote you for your excellent reply.

Well I didn't understand your list example. Can you please give an example? I think I am chopping around the right bush.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Just replace your "if conditions" with lists.

Comment: @LeoDevlar, do you get my idea?

Comment: Yeah. I think you want me to avoid uses of names directly instead of indexes. I used names there is a reason. I am now cross checking my outputs with outputs of online hijri date calenders. Suddenly I got this idea. Till now everything is looking good. Even though I planed at least 15 cross matching with dates upto 2021. As far as I know the Python library I used can only give correct results upto 2021. I ill edit my program once I complete testing my codes comparing with online calendars. Lets do one by one... :)

Comment: @sovolevn I didnt understand this line... 

`hijri_date[2] = islamic_months[hijri_month - 1]`

What we are doing here? Did it means I don't need to use 12 if conditions? Didnt get it.

Comment: @LeoDevlar, yes, you don't need to use 12 conditions. That was my point. I have added comments to my answer.

Comment: Sure. But I have a last question. Why you used `hijri_date[2] = islamic_months[hijri_month - 1]` -1 here? I dont see any reason to do so...

Comment: Because `hijri_month` is in interval [1, 12]. But indexes in list start with 0 and end with 11, so they are in interval [0, 11]. This is the reason for `-1`.

Comment: from your code example I did learn a lot. Many thanks. Specially to improve speed of my software... :)